# Does HDF5 support tuples?

Tags: tuples, hdf5

`HDF5` format supports "hierarchical" data, which means some "paths" to data elements and arrays.

But I don't see if it supports "tuples", i.e. related arrays of data of different size.

Does it?

Comment: I'm not sure I recognise your definition of *tuples* but you may be looking for HDF's `compound` datatypes.  Your search engine will find the documentation of those for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- [**Compound datatype**](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/11_Datatypes.html#CCDtypes): like tuples except the elements are named (like `struct`s in Matlab). Probably your best bet.
- **Array datatype**: fixed size arrays of a single type. Works for homogeneous tuples.

If you want to store just one tuple (or a few of them, but not an *array* of them), you can use a dataset with a null space and store the elements of the tuple in the attributes.